# How to add on webpage finished loading on a webview inside a custom dialog?

Tags: java, android, webview, toast

Im successfully add webview inside of my custom dialog
I want to display toast after the webview finished loading how to add it ?
(it seem theres no need for my code to show)

Comment: showing code is always good, because you would probably want to do something like this - implement the `onPageFinished()` callback of the `WebViewClient` attached to the `WebView`

Answer (score 0):

here's some code that illustrates how to track page loading witha WebView:

```
        webView = rootView.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView).apply {

            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    loadingView.visibility = View.GONE

                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                }

                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    loadingView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }.also {
            it.loadUrl(url)
        }
```